# Recent changes for the worse in the behavior of MathJax

Tags: bug, mathjax

The behavior of MathJax on math.stackexchange.com changed abruptly a few days ago.  It is no longer as good as it was.  Sometimes you see only unrendered code while editing, even after reloading the page.  And sometimes in saved comments you see unrendered code.  This suddenly started happening a few days ago.  What's going on?  Can it be fixed?

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21505/mathjax-2-6-beta) happened. If you have a specific bug that's not yet reported, please report it there.

Comment: If I save a draft of an answer, it may not render into symbols. However, if i then click on the question title to refresh the entire question, everything improves.

Comment: Note the connection with anchored URLs described in the Answer to the early post.